# Apply EF migrations in GitHub workflow on Azure

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core, github-actions

I have a webapi in which I use migrations to update the database, but when I add to github actions:

```
- name: Database update
    run: |
      dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
      dotnet tool restore
      dotnet ef database update -c MyContext -p ./MyProject.WebApi
```

to run migrations, it crashes on error:

> Error Number:-1983577849,State:0,Class:20 A network-related or
> instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
> SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
> that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
> allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 50 - Local
> Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does
> not exist.)

The only thing I can think of is that I should set the IP from which to connect to the database, but I don't know what IP the builds are running from.. Or is there somewhere in Azure to set it to connect to the database from github?

PS: The connection string which I use is copied directly from Azure portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned this is probably the case of allowing to access to your database from Github Runners.

This is possible to whitelist this. But the list is really long.

Please take a look [here - About GitHub's IP addresses](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-githubs-ip-addresses)
. All addresses from action section are needed to be added to you firewall settings.

Here is the link to github api https://api.github.com/meta

```
"actions": [
    "4.148.0.0/16",
    "4.149.0.0/18",
    "4.149.64.0/19",
    "4.149.96.0/19",
    "4.149.128.0/17",
    "4.150.0.0/18",
    "4.150.64.0/18",
    "4.150.128.0/18",
    "4.150.192.0/19",
    "4.150.224.0/19",
.....
```

If you use Azure SQL database you can think about similar approach as it is [here for App Services](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68013299/2347999)